# f[1] raised exception TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
def __init__(self,num=0,denom=1):

    self.num = num 
    self.denom = denom 
    if type(self.num)!= int or type(self.denom)!= int:
        raise AssertionError
    if self.denom < 0:
        self.denom = -self.denom 
        self.num = -self.num 
    if self.num == 0:
        self.denom = 1

    from fractions import gcd
    f = gcd(self.denom,self.num)
    int(f)
    if f < 0:
        f = -f
    self.denom = self.denom/f 
    self.num = self.num /f
    self.denom = int(self.denom)
    self.num = int(self.num)



def __repr__(self):
    s = 'Fraction' + str(('('+str(self.num)+','+str(self.denom)+')'))
    return s


def __str__(self):
    s = str(self.num) +'/'+ str(self.denom)
    return s



def __bool__(self):
    if self.num/self.denom == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True



def __getitem__(self,i):
    if i == 0 or i[0] == 'n':
        return self.num
    if i == 1 or i[0]=='d':
        return self.denom
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

*Instruction*:  Write a `__getitem__` method that returns the numerator for an argument of 0 or any string that is a prefix of 'numerator'; returns the denominator for an argument of 1 or any string that is a prefix of 'denominator'.

For example, if `x = Fraction(1,2)`, then `x[0]` and `x[’num’]` return 1.
*Hint*: see `str.find` function or prefix processing. Raise a `TypeError` in other cases: eg. `x[2]` or `x[’foo’]`.

```
the input is listed as follow:
  43e-->f[1]-->2
  44e-->f['d']-->2
  45e-->f['denom']-->2
  46e-->f['denominator']-->2
  47^-->f[-1]-->TypeError
  48^-->f['x']-->TypeError

the Error I get is: 
  43 *Error: f[1] raised exception TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Can someone tell me what can I do to fix the `__getitem__` function and eliminate the Error?

Comment: always add full error message. there are other interesting information - ie. line which makes problem.

Comment: but that the only Error I got

Comment: it is 43e-->f[1]-->2 that raises a problem

Comment: problem is in `i==0 or i[0]=='d'` - if you use `f[1]` then `i==0` is false so it checks `i[0]==`d` and it tries to do `1[0]=='d'`

Comment: you can use `if isinstance(i, int): # check i` and `if isinstance(i, str) and len(i)>0: # check i[0]`

Comment: @furas can you show me an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is `i==0 or i[0]=='n'`.

When you use `f[1]` then it checks `i==0` (`1==0`) but it gives false so it checks `i[0]=='n'` (`1[0]=='n'`) and you get error.

You could use `isinstance(variable, type)` to check `int` and `str`

```
if isinstance(i, int):
  if i == 0:
      ...
  elif i == 1:
      ...
  else:
      raise ...
elif isinstance(i, str) and len(i)>0:
  if 'numerator'.startswith(i):
      ...
  elif 'denominator'.startswith(i):
      ...
  else:
      raise ...
else:
  raise ...
```